# How to assign current date with specific time to column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, ssis

How do i assign current date with a specific time?

let's say 8:00:00 AM to Column EXIT_DT of datatype `datetime`??

I have tried `GETDATE()` AS EXIT_DT but it gives me current datetime. I am using Sql server 2005. Any help?

Lets say Today is 1/3/2013 and i want my result to return as a datetime datatype with value 1/3/2013 8:00:00 AM. If i run the statement ytd, the result will be 1/2/2013 8:00:00 AM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This formula will always produce 08:00 for the day it is called, and avoids string manipulation:

```
select DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T08:00:00')
```

Try to avoid solutions that convert to and from strings - treating datetime values as strings is one of the largest sources of bugs.

It works by computing the number of days (as an integer) that have elapsed since 1st January 2001. It then adds that same number of days to 08:00 on 1st January 2001.

Comment: Other answers might work too but urs really short and sweet. Smart!

Comment: Awesome!! Just awesome.!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
DECLARE  @dt datetime;

SET @dt=CONVERT(DateTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101)+' 8:00:00')

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @dt, 101)+'  '+ LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@dt, 100), 7))
```

Visit http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx for `datetime` formats.

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert along with getdate() to get specific formats.

ex:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),113)
```

Comment: i tried this does not achieve what i want. and i want the result of the datatype datetime not varchar(30). Any further help?

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),113))

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit stupid, but it works

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + '08:00:00'
```

it casts the `getdate()` to `date` thus losing the hours, than it casts it to `datetime` and adds 8 hours.

If you want to avoid implicit conversion of `varchar` to `datetime`, you  could use this version:

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) 
     + convert(datetime,'08:00:00',114)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working. (1). convert today's date to `ISO format (yyyymmdd)`  (2). add the time, (3). convert back to datetime

```
Select convert(datetime, convert(varchar, getdate(),112) + ' ' + '8:00:00AM')
--Results
2013-01-03 08:00:00.000
```

If you need in specific format you need to convert back to varchar again.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- AM/PM --
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM dual
/

-- 24 hrs format --
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
/
```