# Sql query, insert current day but not current time

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a sql query there i want to insert the current day but same time every day but this code is not working. The field in database is datetime. The output of this code is 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO (table)
        VALUES(CONCAT(CURDATE(),'14:00:00'))";
```

If i change to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO (table)
    VALUES(CONCAT(CURDATE()))";
```

Then the outcome is 2016-10-30 00:00:00 so it must be something wrong with the time.

Comment: are you using SQL server, Oracle, MySQL ?

Comment: Please add tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you can use:

```
CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 10:07:50')
```

or check this link:
[How to assign current date with specific time to column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136197/how-to-assign-current-date-with-specific-time-to-column)

Comment: Yes, i'm using MySQL and code above is not working for me. My field in database is timestamp. Maybe something with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `NOW()` function.

```
create table test1(d timestamp);

insert into test1 values(now());
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c65db/1)**

**===Updated===**

```
insert into test1 values('2012-04-30 12:12:23');
```

Assuming you are using `php`, then you could create a variable and assign date value like below :

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d').' 12:22:30';
```

Comment: But that creates the time right now. I want to put in my own time.

Comment: Check my updated post. Same you can try on SQLFiddle.

Comment: Yes i can use that code but i want it put in the current day without i have to change it every day. But the same time very day.

Comment: If you see, it is a string, so you can use your programming language to manipulate it and then pass it here. You got it . right ?

Comment: check the latest post. Please accept the answer, if you got the answer.

Comment: Yes, i'm using PHP and i'm still a noob in this. My code are now: $dt = date('Y-m-d'). '14:00:00'; and $sql= "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES('$dt')"; but the outcome is still 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: <?php
 function function1() { 
 include("connect.php"); 
 $dt = date('Y-m-d').'12:22:30';
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1) 
   VALUES('$dt')";
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
 } else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);

mysqli_close($conn);
}
}
?>

Comment: try following :
1. echo $dt.
2. remove single quote from `VALUES('$dt')`

Comment: Echo $dt; on a new line or inside values?

Answer (score -1):

For Oracle it may be:

```
INSERT INTO table (field)
VALUES (sysdate);
```

Comment: That w'll insert the current `datetime`